# Google Calendar API - Update Attendees and only send emails to new attendees

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to update an event in my Gsuite calendar via the API.

My goal is to mimic what the UI does:

- add an event
- update the list of attendees
- email invites only go to the new attendees

When I try this using the `update` method in the API, all my attendees get an email.

I then tried to update the parameter `sendUpdates` but it only has 3 options:

- `all` - email everyone
- `none` - email no-one
- `externalOnly` - email external only

I can't use `patch` either as the API doesn't support `attendees` patching.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
*I hate that the UI can do it but I cannot!*

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Also, please specify the programming language you are using in conjunction with the `Google Calendar API`

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way. Maybe add an snipped of the code will help.

Comment: with out an example and more details its hard to answer.  We dont even know what language they are using.

Comment: The api does support attendees patching.